# Does alamofire handle resuming downloads after app is restarted?

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am wondering if the `Alamofire` SDK for Swift 3 handles resuming File downloads when an app is restarted? As I understand it, it downloads the file to the `temp` directory until it is completed, and then moves the file to the designated place. If this download gets interrupted, does it look for that file, and then set the Request headers to continue the operation?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to manage it yourself.

Comment: It's what i thought. I guess you can look to see if the file in the temp directory exists and then set the Range bytes header to start the download from a set point.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.